# Error setting up workplace for Minecraft Modding

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I've just started working on Minecraft modding. I was following along with a couple tutorials, but as soon as I tried to set up the workspace, it failed. I'm trying to mod the 1.7.10 version of Minecraft and I tried multiple methods of setting up a workspace (one of them being using the gradlew setupDecompWorkspace command, the other using gradlew setupDevWorkspace eclipse). Neither of these worked and I got the same errors only varying on the "total time" at the very end. I tried a bunch of different methods to try and fix this. I tried reinstalling Java multiple times and nothing worked. Here is the code:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:common:[3.2.0,4.0.0).
     Required by:
         :forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:jobs:3.5.300-v20130429-1813
         :forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:contenttype:3.4.200-v20130326-1255
         :forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.equinox:preferences:3.5.100-v20130422-1538
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:common.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/common/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/common/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:preferences:[3.2.0,4.0.0).
     Required by:
         :forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:contenttype:3.4.200-v20130326-1255
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:preferences.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/preferences/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/preferences/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:registry:[3.2.0,4.0.0).
     Required by:
         :forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:contenttype:3.4.200-v20130326-1255
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:registry.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/registry/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/registry/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.core.runtime:compatibility:[3.1.0,4.0.0).
     Required by:
         :forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:resources:3.2.1-R32x_v20060914
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.core.runtime:compatibility.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/runtime/compatibility/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/runtime/compatibility/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.core:expressions:[3.1.0,4.0.0).
     Required by:
         :forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:resources:3.2.1-R32x_v20060914
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.core:expressions.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/expressions/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/expressions/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.core:filesystem:[1.0.0,2.0.0).
     Required by:
         :forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:resources:3.2.1-R32x_v20060914
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.core:filesystem.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/filesystem/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/filesystem/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse:osgi:[3.7.0,4.0.0).
     Required by:
         :forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse:osgi.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/osgi/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/osgi/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:common:[3.6.100,4.0.0).
     Required by:
         :forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:common.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/common/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/common/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.core:jobs:[3.2.0,4.0.0).
     Required by:
         :forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.core:jobs.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/jobs/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/jobs/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:registry:[3.4.0,4.0.0).
     Required by:
         :forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:registry.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/registry/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/registry/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:preferences:[3.4.0,4.0.0).
     Required by:
         :forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:preferences.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/preferences/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/preferences/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.core:contenttype:[3.3.0,4.0.0).
     Required by:
         :forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.core:contenttype.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/contenttype/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/contenttype/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:app:[1.0.0,2.0.0).
     Required by:
         :forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10-src:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT > org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255
      > Failed to list versions for org.eclipse.equinox:app.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/app/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/app/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 10.223 secs
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you for reading.